# Unable to Create textView and editText onClick (although method is reached in debugger)

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-xml

I have a textView and an editText which should be displayed below my imageView (sqwhite) however for some reason - I cannot see either the textView (tx) or the editText (et) (after clicking the button which successfully displays the imageView).

The strange part is I can debug and step through these methods... yet no textView or editText ever seems to appear on the screen (the imageView sqwhite appears without issue though).

### Java Snippet:

```
private boolean isErase = false;
private EditText et;
private TextView tx;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.demo);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

...

```
public void addNewImageToScreen() {
        int resourceId = R.drawable.sqwhite;
        addNewTextToScreen();
        int m = mImageCount % 3;

        if (m == 1)
            resourceId = R.drawable.sqdrk;

        else if (m == 2)
            resourceId = R.drawable.sqwhite;
        addNewImageToScreen(resourceId);

    }

    private void addNewTextToScreen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (isErase) {
            tx.setText(et.getText().toString());
        } else {
            tx.setText("");
            et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        isErase = !isErase;
    }
```

### XML Snippet:

```
  <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sqwhite"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/sqwhite" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you are endlessly recursing through `addNewImageToScreen(...)`?

Comment: Yes - in order to be able to endlessly cycle through (folder) images which can be added to the screen (it is intentional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you go through addNewTextToScreen, isErase is false, so the visibility is set to gone. That's why it doesn't appear

Comment: Changing private boolean isErase = to true results in the same thing (no textView no editText)

Comment: I'm missing something here. I see you have et and tx but you never assign them with findViewById. I'm guessing that is in a part of the code we haven't seen. Other than that, you're setting your imageview with fillparents in a container that uses wrapcontents, so maybe you're pushing those controls out of sight. try reducing your image's height and see if that's it.

Comment: Ok - I posted the entire source here: http://pastebin.com/iMbd1pNm (it should clear up anything I might have overlooked in this post) I'm going to try that now - I'll reply back here in a few minutes

Comment: This is somewhat interesting... for some reason if I use:   <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_source_frame"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" > the edit text appears - but if I use                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                it appears huge (yet still sq - I would expect a rectangle if the height is almost double the length)

Comment: How can I modify the XML so there is enough room for both without increasing or decreasing the (actual) size of sqwhite

Comment: After putting your XML file into Eclipse, a LOT of errors and/or simple problems become apparent. You have a lot of extraneous (useless) layouts, and you have invalid parameters all over the place. Are you paying attention to the errors that eclipse gives you? Anyway, one problem is that the `LinearLayout` containing the bottom row is set to horizontal, so the `FrameLayout` is pushed into an area in the lower righthand corner. This is a problem. Fix all the warnings that Eclipse gives you, play around with the WYSIWYG layout editor to find your missing views, and tell me what happens.

Comment: Changing the bottom LinearLayout from horizontal to vertical completely ruins the formatting of everything... I've attached the complete source as a zip if you'd like to take a closer look http://www.sendspace.com/file/9kdrvj

Comment: as long as you use fill_parent in your imageview, it will always push the controls out. However, I see your relativelayout can easily be replaced with a vertical linearlayout since you have a line of controls. if you do that, you can use "weight" to place all the control inside the layout.

Comment: I changed the relativelayout to a linearlayout and set the height and width to 100dp - what do you suggest I use as the weight parameter? (Should I apply it to all elements within the linearlayout or just one?) 


http://pastebin.com/H0c1PLNX

(thank you for your help with this BTW! Feel free to post as an answer once we're done and I'll gladly give you credit for the answer)

Comment: As of the weight, you'll have to experiment. I'd put a weightsum of 100 in the linearlayout, then set the layout_height of the items inside to 0dp and, maybe start with 90, 5 and 5, from there you only have to experiment until it looks like you want.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? I'm having a few other issues with this build as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913058/android-xml-layout-parameters-do-not-function-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of your ImageView are set to fill_parent, that is likely pushing your other views offscreen. At the very minimum, height should be changed to something else.

Comment: I tried just now to set it to 100dp... it seems to make no difference:


http://pastebin.com/eYPXyf9K